# Conflict between jquery and bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some problems with multiple js files. When I tried adding the lightgallery plugin to a page I noticed it didn't work for some reason. After a long while I found out it was because of bootstrap.js , when I remove it the lightgallery works, but now my fixed menu stops working.

So depending on what file I comment out, different things start and stop working. I would like that everything works with both files.

My list of js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/appear.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/featherlight.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.shuffle.modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/spsimpleportfolio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rev-tool.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/revolation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/count-down.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parallex.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

The errors I get in the console:

[image]

When I click on the first error it points to this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lightgallery").lightGallery();
    });
</script>
```

[I added my bootstrap.js file here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ojkkf7cb/)

Comment: have you tried using [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: which version of bootstrap you use?

Comment: @Pete Yes but I also read that noConflict doesn't apply to bootstrap/jquery conflicts, only conflicts between multiple jquery versions.

Comment: @Dekel version 3.3.5

Comment: If you read the first line of the link: *Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does.* noConflict works for anything that has a conflict with jQuery as it allows you to change jQuery from using `$` to what you want

Comment: And are you sure that all of the other libraries you use support jQuery3 ?

Comment: try to use jquery 1.12.x for all browsers (IE and Edge have problems with any Version of 2 and 3). after that try to use 2.x get running with your libraries. i'm sure owl carousel uses max jquery 2 and not 3 if he has not updatet in the last month for example

Comment: @Dekel No I'm not sure, atthe moment I'm only sure there is a problem betweetn bootstrap.js and my jquery version (I tried different versions)

Comment: Support for jquery 3 was added only on bootstrap 3.3.7 (and you are not using this version). You should use jquery 2 or jquery 1